# How to find number of numbers formed with given digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question is Find the number of numbers of five digits that can be made with the digits of the number 1203210. Can you please explain the problem? I did not understand it. Although one asked similar question, I was unable to follow. Can I use multinomial or binary method to solve these problems? Answer is 258

Comment: It is simply asking how many $5$ digit numbers $abcbd$ can you make using the digits $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Since you have only $4$ digits available therefore something must repeat. Most likely (depends on authors of the book) it would also mean that a number should not start with $0$. For example $11230$ is valid but $01233$ is not.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use $0$ at most twice, same with $1$ and $2$, while $3$ is used at most once.

Comment: Does it mean that we can fill tenthousand place in 3 ways, 1000place in 4 ways, 100th place in 4 ways, 10th place in 4 ways and ones place in 4 ways? as the repetition is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question means that you can draw digits only from the given #, i.e. two each of 0's, 1's, and 2's and only one of 3.

Remember, a # can't start with a 0.

The solution can easily be obtained using a generating function.

Without restricting *0* at start, numbers possible will be given by

coefficient of $x^5$ in $5!(1+x)(1+x + x^2/2!)^3 = 360$

subtract from this numbers of 4 digits (having only one 0 left), so

coefficient of $x^4 in 4!(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2/2!)^2 = 102

360 - 102 = 258

I can't see an easy way to do it otherwise, but as I said, it is very late here, I'll see later if it is reasonably easy to do it without a G.F.

---

The best I can do is to categorise as follows [ *revised categorisation* ]

(i) Both 0's present and can be placed in ${4\choose 2} = 6 $ ways. [Three from 11223 left to fit in 3 spaces]

Those containing a "double" [112,113,221,223 ] can be permutes in 3 ways each, and 123 can be permuted in 6 ways $\Rightarrow 6\cdot(4\cdot3 +6) = 108$

(ii) One 0 present, placed in 4 ways [Four needed from 11223] 1123 and 2213 can be permuted in 12 ways, while 1122 can be permuted in 6 ways$\Rightarrow 4(2\cdot12 + 6) = 120$

(iii) No 0 present:[5 needed from 11223] $dfrac{5!}{2!2!}=30

Finally, **108+120+30 = 258**

Still, I advise use the G.F. Such problems may come in different forms, and it is a tedious error prone process.

Comment: For that case I got the no.of selections as 10. Should permute the numbers to get that.

Comment: I have solved it. Hopefully, you have studied generating functions. If not, try to enumerate systematically !

Comment: Thanks alot. Thats what I asked. Thanks for explaining the problem by multinomial(generating functions).

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the significant numbers that can be formed using digits $0$, $1$, $2$ & $3$ should not have first digit $0$. Hence, first place can be filled by any of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ & each of other four places can be filled  by 4 ways $\{0, 1, 2, 4\}$

hence assuming that the repetition of digits is allowed, the total 5-digit numbers $$=3\times4\times 4\times 4\times 4=768$$

Comment: answer is 258..

Comment: By the way 3x4x4x4x4 is 768

Comment: yes, you are right but you didn't provide any information about the repetition or non-repetition of digits.

Comment: They did not provide anything about that.

Comment: So the answers obtained are different using different ways

Comment: Still working on that problem. There are 4,5 problems like that. Without understanding the probelem doing it is waste I think. Even if I get hint to 1 question, My problem is over

Answer (score 0):

A) If the number has no zeros, then there are $\frac{5!}{2!2!}=\color{red}{30}$ possibilities.

B) If the number has exactly 1 zero, then there are $4\binom{4}{2}=\color{red}{24}$ possibilities if it does not contain a 3,

$\hspace{.2 in}$and $2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3=\color{red}{96}$ possibilities if it does contain a 3

$\hspace{.2 in}$(since there are 2 choices for the repeated digit, and $4\cdot4\cdot3$ ways to arrange the digits).

C) If the number has 2 zeros, then there are $\binom{4}{2}\cdot6=\color{red}{36}$ possibilities if 0 is the only repeated digit

$\hspace{.2 in}$and $2\cdot2\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot3=\color{red}{72}$ possibilities if there is another repeated digit

(since there are 2 choices for the other repeated digit, 2 choices for the 3rd digit, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to place the zeros, and 3 ways to place the nonrepeated digit).

This gives a total of $\color{red}{258}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A way of computing the number of "words" you can make out of MISSISSIPPI ($4 \times I, 1 \times M, 4 \times S, 2 \times P$) is to take the $4 + 1 + 4 + 2 = 11$ letters with subindices to distinguish equal letters, i.e., consider permuting $I_1 I_2 I_3 I_4 M S_1 S_2 S_3 S_4 P_1 P_2$, which can be done in $11!$ ways. But if you erase the indices from the $I$s, you see that a factor of $4!$ alternative words dissapear. Do the same for all, you end up with:

$$
\frac{11!}{4!\,1!\,4!\,2!} = \binom{11}{4, 1, 4, 2}
$$

a multinomial coefficient.

In your case, there are $2 \times 0,  2 \times 1, 2 \times 2, 1 \times 3$,
this would give:

$$ 
\binom{2+2+2+1}{2, 2, 2, 1} = 630
$$

But presumably starting with $0$ is forbidden. One way to handle that is to consider you have to distribute the two zeros in the 6 positions that aren't the first one (for

$$
\binom{6}{2} = 15
$$

options), and compute the ways of shuffling the rest of the digits in order to the still free positions (there are

$$
\binom{2+2+1}{2,2,1} = 30
$$

ways to do this). The decision of placing the $0$ and the other digits are independent, so the total is:

$$
\binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{2+2+1}{2,2,1} = 15 \cdot 30 = 450
$$